# which is the function that removes accented vowels?

Tags: functions, themes, slug

Which is the function WP uses to convert words like "voilà" and "novità" to "voila" and "novita" in category slug? Can I recall it in my theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to covert accented words you can use [remove_accents()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_accents)

If you want it converted in a slug like format you can use [sanitize_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title)